# Jquery in TPL file prestashop

Tags: jquery, smarty3, prestashop-1.7

I want call my function fullTxtFunc for to display all my text bloc. i see not the alert(fullTxt) and I a have also an error in firebug:
my file Category.tpl:

```
{block name='product_list_header'} 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
{literal}
$(document).ready(function(){

      function fullTxtFunc()
      {
        var fullTxt = {/literal}"{$category.description nofilter}";{literal}
        alert("fullTxt");
      }
     // $('.displayFullTxt').click(function(){

      //});

});
{/literal}

</script>
    <div class="block-category card card-block hidden-sm-down">
      <h1 class="h1">{$category.name}</h1>
      {if $category.description}
        <div id="category-description" class="text-muted">{$category.description|truncate:750:" ..." nofilter}<span class="fullTxt" onclick="fullTxtFunc();">Lire la suite</span></div>
        <div class="category-cover">
          <img src="{$category.image.large.url}" alt="{$category.image.legend}">
        </div>
      {/if}
    </div>
    <div class="text-xs-center hidden-md-up">
      <h1 class="h1">{$category.name}</h1>
    </div>
{/block}
```

error firebug:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOMJo.png)
Thank's for ur help!

Comment: You could separate JavaScript from HTML and put data on the data attribute of the HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code:

```
function fullTxtFunc()
      {
        var fullTxt = '{/literal}{$category.description nofilter}{literal}';
        alert("fullTxt");
      }
```

Comment: you can use `encodeURIComponent` function for this.

Comment: Thank's it's resolved, It was necessary to use the addEventListener function